# Uploading a base64 image from IOS to S3 using Node.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3, base64

I have the following code to upload an image from ios device to AWS S3 using node.js:

```
  var buf = new Buffer(req.body.image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64')

  var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'forplay-static', Key: 'test.png'}});
  s3bucket.putObject(buf, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send({ success: false, err: err });
    } else {
      return res.send({ success: true });
    }
  });
```

The image I am posting is: http://pastebin.com/kcmXJbRd

This returns the following error in err:

```
{ "code": "UnexpectedParameter", "name": "UnexpectedParameter" }
```

What is the correct way of uploading a base64 image to S3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't create a bucket with a key. Keys identify the resources within the buckets. Not sure what AWS client you're using, so I'm not sure EXACTLY what it should look like, but probably something like this:

```
var buf = new Buffer(req.body.image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64')

var s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.putObject({Bucket: 'forplay-static', Key: 'test.png', Body: buf}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return res.send({ success: false, err: err });
  } else {
    return res.send({ success: true });
  }
});
```

EDIT: Now that I know aws-sdk, I've changed the code above based on the docs [here](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornodejs/). I just skipped the `createBucket` step. You pass the bucket and key parameter to the putObject method, NOT the AWS.S3 constructor.

Comment: I am not trying to create a new bucket, just trying to add a new image to my existing one.

Comment: And I am using official aws sdk for node.js.

Comment: can you please explain me first line why we replace this. and you already pass base64 data?

Comment: I just copied the OPs example, but basically, you've got base64 data, but you need it in a buffer, not a string, so you have to strip off the leading "data:image/png;base64" part that identifies what type of data it is (the replace does this), and then create a base64 buffer of the actual image content.

Comment: Okay but I got Buffer is undefined error. Any solution for the same. I am new in this so confused

Comment: Buffer is undefined? Are you trying to do this from the browser? Buffer has been built in to node.js for (literally) years. And if you are _in_ node already, you should probably ask a new question, as that's not really related to this question.